# Identify this sliding door hardware

Tags: doors, hardware

Now that I've been able to [remove the doors from the track](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/246484/is-there-a-way-to-remove-this-sliding-door-without-taking-down-the-trim), I see that the hardware doesn't look as much like [Hettich 7000-series](https://web.hettich.com/en-us/products-catalog/architectural-sliding-and-folding-door-systems) as I originally thought:

- Hettich's double track (part 7003) has a profile that looks like this:

  [image: Hettich 7000 track]

  My track looks like this:

  [image: My track]

  Note the recess in the underside of the track
- My top plate and carrier look like this (note that the carrier is badly bent, the wheel sets should be close to parallel to each other):

  [image: top plate and carrier]

  Using Archive.org's Wayback Machine, I was able to find Hettich America catalogs from all the way back to 2004. None of them have a part that looks even remotely like these parts.

None of the parts have any identifying marks on them.

Other brands I have checked that do not match (both current products and old catalogs via Archive.org) include:

- **Barton-Kramer**
- **Hafele**
- **Johnson Hardware** - 200-series is close, but they do not make a double track, only a single I-beam track
- **National Hardware**
- **Prime-Line**

Most of those companies (except Johnson) appear to not make a bottom guide track, which my doors have.

I tried looking for the company that made the door pulls, but they are [from idh by St. Simmons](http://www.idhbrass.com/product-p/14020.htm), which does not make tracks and carriers.

How can I figure out the brand of this hardware so I can try to find replacement parts?

Comment: If you don't mind, a frame challenge: instead of trying to match the existing damaged hardware, try getting new hardware, track and all. Then all the parts will fit.

Comment: Yeah, bypass door hardware isn't that expensive. I'd probably start fresh, too. Just look for a kit with good wheels so they're quieter and smoother.

Comment: What parts do you need? I'd have bent that stuff back into shape and popped it back up. Metal doesn't usually fatigue enough from two incidents to require replacement.

Comment: @Triplefault I would have to take down drywall in order to access the screws at the far ends of the track inside the pockets.

Comment: @isherwood I would just bend the metal back into shape, except that the vinyl wheels are quite badly worn out, which is what allowed this to jump off the track in the first place. I also need to replace the runners that go in the floor track, because some of them have broken off.

Comment: I have never seen the wheels split so far apart, they are usually parallel and a screw moves them higher or lower those look like they were maxed out and folded in.

Comment: If by chance those wheels are 3/4" or 7/8" you can replace them with a oval edge shower door rollers. Grind off or drill out the rivet that holds the wheel on and bolt on the shower door roller. You can also check C.R. Laurence Co. for something that might work. https://www.crlaurence.com/crlapps/showline/default.aspx?GroupID=58908&History=39326:1:39325:58906&pom=0

Comment: @EdBeal they didn't used to be so far apart, until the door fell off the track and someone tried to pull it anyway.

Comment: Find a local metal fabrication shop, bring them a set of good pieces and have them fab some replacements for you. Roller wheels should be available at hardware stores or online. The fab work might be expensive (the blacksmith down the road from me charged $75/hour 10 years ago and wouldn't give me a time estimate), but it might be cheaper than redoing all the drywall.